# Can my idea that was published in my own blog still be patentable by me?

Tags: patentability, invention, websites, idea, blogs

**Can my idea that was published in my own blog still be patentable by me?**

**Case 1:**

I have an innovative solution of a problem that was published in my websites blog. After couple of years I rethink and feel it should be patented. By this time many people already have read my innovation on my blog and also copied in other sites referring my original blog page. At this point, Is this idea still be patentable by me?

**Case 2:**

Another scenario, let's say, some people improved my original invention and discussed in their own websites. At this point, If I want to patent only my core idea without others (those people who improved my core idea and discussed on their websites) improvements, Is this idea still be patentable by me?

Comment: Although not required, it would be helpful for the downvoter to explain their vote in the hope that the OP can improve the question.

Comment: That was me and I retracted it - I thought it showed little research but the Q plus the A is useful to others who do some research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No and No to the concept published two years ago. In most of the world no to anything already published yesterday. In the US there is a 1 year sort-of grace period so the concepts of others might or might not fall within that time frame.

A question not asked is - can concepts *not yet published* that are improvements or offshoots to your original concept be patented, either by you or others. Yes you or they could. That is very different from a 2 year old public concept.